# Passing Global Variable from One Evaluated Page to Another

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

So I have some code and I would like to pass a variable outside so I can evaluate another page and inject the code from the previous page.

I'm not an expert here and I'm just not grasping the concept. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
var scheduleArray = [];

//blah blah removed code...everything works up to this point

casper.thenEvaluate(function(scheduleArray){

    console.log("##Your schedule is " + document.querySelector('form + div table').textContent );
    var rawSchedule = document.querySelector('form + div table').textContent;
    scheduleArray = rawSchedule.match(/((Monday)|(Tuesday)|(Wednesday)|(Thursday)|(Friday)|(Saturday)|(Sunday))([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4})((5)|(C6)|(6)|(7H)|(7F)|(715)|(8F)|(10F)|(12F)|(1F)|(2H)|(C2)|(2))/gi);
    console.log("##scheduleArray");
    console.log(scheduleArray);

    for (i=0;i<scheduleArray.length;i++){
        console.log(scheduleArray[i]);
    }


},scheduleArray);

casper.then(function(scheduleArray){
    console.log("##scheduleArray");
//This loop contains no data
    for (i=0;i<scheduleArray.length;i++){
            console.log(scheduleArray[i]);
        }
},scheduleArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a small sample code for you to illustrate how to passing result between evaluate and the casper script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

var array = []

casper.start('http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC39.htm');

casper.then(function() {
    array = casper.evaluate(function () {
        var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('a')
        var result = Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function (div) {
            return div.href
        })
        return result
    });
});

casper.then(function () {
    casper.echo(array.length);
    casper.echo(array.join("\n"))
})

casper.run()
```

Output:

```
22
http://www.ecma-international.org/default.htm
http://www.ecma-international.org/contact/contact.html
http://www.ecma-international.org/sitemap/ecma_sitemap.html
http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/index.html
http://www.ecma-international.org/activities/index.html
http://www.ecma-international.org/news/index.html
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/index.html
http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/history.htm
... ignore some lines
```

---

So, come to your code:

1. The change of the argument of `evaluate` doesn't take that change to your global variable. That is to say, what ever you do to `scheduleArray` inside `evaluate`, the global variable `scheduleArray` remains the same.
2. Inside `evaluate`, you should use `console.log` to log, but outside the `evaluate`, you should use `casper.echo`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however scheduleArray still does not return a result :(

Comment: @user6571666 I edit my solution, feel free to leave a comment if there is any further question.

Comment: that is a wonderfully simple solution, thank you so much for your time, I understand now that you are using prototype and returning the value or the array as evaluate.

Comment: @user6571666 If there is no further question, please remember to accept my answer...